# Is it possible to get the PnPDeviceId of a Network Adapter without using WMI?

Tags: c#, network-programming, pinvoke

I have been trying to get the PnPDeviceId of a given network adapter using p/invoke setupapi calls with no success. I settled, reluctantly, for using WMI, like so:

```
public static string GetPnpDeviceId(string mac)
{
    ManagementObjectCollection mo = Management.GetCollection("Win32_NetworkAdapter", "PNPDeviceID", "MACAddress = '" + mac + "'");
    return GetFirstValueString(mo, "PNPDeviceID");
}

public static ManagementObjectCollection GetCollection(string WMIClass, string WMISelect="*", string WMIWhere="")
{

    string qry = "SELECT " + WMISelect + " FROM " + WMIClass + (WMIWhere == "" ? "" : " WHERE " + WMIWhere);
    ObjectQuery oq = new System.Management.ObjectQuery(qry);
    ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oq);
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = query.Get();
    return queryCollection;
}

public static string GetFirstValueString(ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection, string WMIValue)
{
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
    {
        object o = mo[WMIValue];
        return (string)o;
    }
    return "";
}
```

The p/invoke apis seem complicated to get right but the overhead of loading the Management classes (especially Win32_NetworkAdapter it seems) for such a simple call seems excessive. Can anyone tell me if this is possible even with p/invoke or better still tell me where to find the value in the api calls and i'll go from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, i solved it by myself. it's a lot of code but the performance is worth it imho.
the WMI call takes about 800ms each whereas the pinvoke one takes about 25ms. anyway here's the code (rough & ready- few comments):

```
class NetPnP
{
    internal static Guid GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET = new Guid("CAC88484-7515-4C03-82E6-71A87ABAC361");

    public static string GetPnPDeviceId(NetworkInterface ni)
    {
        Guid classGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET;
        IntPtr hwndParent = IntPtr.Zero;
        Int32 flags = Win32DeviceMgmt.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | Win32DeviceMgmt.DIGCF_PRESENT;
        IntPtr pDevInfoSet = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr pNewDevInfoSet = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            pNewDevInfoSet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, IntPtr.Zero, hwndParent, flags);//, pDevInfoSet, strMachineName, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (pNewDevInfoSet == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Logger.Log("Failed to get device information list");
                return "";
            }

            Int32 iRet;
            Int32 iMemberIndex = 0;
            do
            {
                Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = new Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                devInfoData.ClassGuid = Guid.Empty;
                devInfoData.DevInst = 0;
                devInfoData.Reserved = UIntPtr.Zero;
                devInfoData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(devInfoData);

                iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(pNewDevInfoSet, iMemberIndex, ref devInfoData);
                if (iRet == 0)
                {
                    Int32 iLastError = Win32DeviceMgmt.GetLastError();
                    if (iLastError == Win32DeviceMgmt.ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("No more devices in list");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iMemberIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                string desc = GetDevicePropertyString(pNewDevInfoSet, devInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum.SPDRP_DEVICEDESC);
                if (ni.Description.Equals(desc)) return GetDeviceInstanceId(pNewDevInfoSet, devInfoData);
                string friendly = GetDevicePropertyString(pNewDevInfoSet, devInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum.SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME);
                if (ni.Description.Equals(friendly)) return GetDeviceInstanceId(pNewDevInfoSet, devInfoData);

                iMemberIndex++;
            } while (true);
            return "";
        }
        finally
        {
            Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(pNewDevInfoSet);
        }
    }

    static String GetDeviceInstanceId(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData)
    {
        StringBuilder strId = new StringBuilder(0);
        Int32 iRequiredSize = 0;
        Int32 iSize = 0;
        Int32 iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData, strId, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);
        strId = new StringBuilder(iRequiredSize);
        iSize = iRequiredSize;
        iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData, strId, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);
        if (iRet == 1)
        {
            return strId.ToString();
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }

    static String GetDevicePropertyString(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum property)
    {
        byte[] ptrBuf = GetDeviceProperty(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceInfoData, property);
        return ptrBuf.ToStrAuto();
    }

    static Guid GetDevicePropertyGuid(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum property)
    {
        byte[] ptrBuf = GetDeviceProperty(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceInfoData, property);
        return new Guid(ptrBuf);
    }

    static byte[] GetDeviceProperty(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum property)
    {
        StringBuilder strId = new StringBuilder(0);
        byte[] ptrBuf= null;
        UInt32 RegType;
        UInt32 iRequiredSize = 0;
        UInt32 iSize = 0;
        bool iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData,
            (uint)property, out RegType, ptrBuf, iSize, out iRequiredSize);
        ptrBuf = new byte[iRequiredSize];
        iSize = iRequiredSize;
        iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData,
            (uint)property, out RegType, ptrBuf, iSize, out iRequiredSize);
        if (iRet)
        {
            return ptrBuf;
        }

        return new byte[0];
    }

}

public static class ByteArrayEx
{   
    public static string ToStrAuto(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        string ret = "";


        IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, unmanagedPointer, bytes.Length);
            // Call unmanaged code
            ret = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(unmanagedPointer);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
public class Win32DeviceMgmt
{
    internal static Int32 ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES = 259;

    internal static Int32 LINE_LEN = 256;

    internal static Int32 DIGCF_DEFAULT = 0x00000001;  // only valid with DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002;
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x00000004;
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_PROFILE = 0x00000008;
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000010;

    internal static Int32 SPINT_ACTIVE = 0x00000001;
    internal static Int32 SPINT_DEFAULT = 0x00000002;
    internal static Int32 SPINT_REMOVED = 0x00000004;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Size of structure in bytes
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 cbSize;
        /// <summary>
        /// GUID of the device interface class
        /// </summary>
        public Guid ClassGuid;
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle to this device instance
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 DevInst;
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved; do not use. 
        /// </summary>
        public UIntPtr Reserved;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Size of the structure, in bytes
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 cbSize;
        /// <summary>
        /// GUID of the device interface class
        /// </summary>
        public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 Flags;
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved; do not use.
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr Reserved;

    };


    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevsEx(ref Guid ClassGuid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, Int32 Flags, IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String MachineName, IntPtr Reserved);
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(           // 1st form using a ClassGUID only, with null Enumerator
       ref Guid ClassGuid,
       IntPtr Enumerator,
       IntPtr hwndParent,
       int Flags
    );
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, IntPtr DeviceInfoData, IntPtr InterfaceClassGuid, Int32 MemberIndex, ref  SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Int32 MemberIndex, ref  SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiClassNameFromGuid(ref Guid ClassGuid, StringBuilder className, Int32 ClassNameSize, ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiGetClassDescription(ref Guid ClassGuid, StringBuilder classDescription, Int32 ClassDescriptionSize, ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, 
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, 
        StringBuilder DeviceInstanceId, 
        Int32 DeviceInstanceIdSize, 
        ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// The SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function retrieves the specified device property.
    /// This handle is typically returned by the SetupDiGetClassDevs or SetupDiGetClassDevsEx function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param Name="DeviceInfoSet">Handle to the device information set that contains the interface and its underlying device.</param>
    /// <param Name="DeviceInfoData">Pointer to an SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure that defines the device instance.</param>
    /// <param Name="Property">Device property to be retrieved. SEE MSDN</param>
    /// <param Name="PropertyRegDataType">Pointer to a variable that receives the registry data Type. This parameter can be NULL.</param>
    /// <param Name="PropertyBuffer">Pointer to a buffer that receives the requested device property.</param>
    /// <param Name="PropertyBufferSize">Size of the buffer, in bytes.</param>
    /// <param Name="RequiredSize">Pointer to a variable that receives the required buffer size, in bytes. This parameter can be NULL.</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.</returns>
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
        uint Property,
        out UInt32 PropertyRegDataType,
        byte[] PropertyBuffer,
        uint PropertyBufferSize,
        out UInt32 RequiredSize
        );

    // Device Property
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DEVPROPKEY
    {
        public Guid fmtid;
        public UInt32 pid;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 GetLastError();
}
/// <summary>
/// Flags for SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty().
/// </summary>
enum SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum : uint
{
    SPDRP_DEVICEDESC = 0x00000000, // DeviceDesc (R/W)
    SPDRP_HARDWAREID = 0x00000001, // HardwareID (R/W)
    SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS = 0x00000002, // CompatibleIDs (R/W)
    SPDRP_UNUSED0 = 0x00000003, // unused
    SPDRP_SERVICE = 0x00000004, // Service (R/W)
    SPDRP_UNUSED1 = 0x00000005, // unused
    SPDRP_UNUSED2 = 0x00000006, // unused
    SPDRP_CLASS = 0x00000007, // Class (R--tied to ClassGUID)
    SPDRP_CLASSGUID = 0x00000008, // ClassGUID (R/W)
    SPDRP_DRIVER = 0x00000009, // Driver (R/W)
    SPDRP_CONFIGFLAGS = 0x0000000A, // ConfigFlags (R/W)
    SPDRP_MFG = 0x0000000B, // Mfg (R/W)
    SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME = 0x0000000C, // FriendlyName (R/W)
    SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION = 0x0000000D, // LocationInformation (R/W)
    SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME = 0x0000000E, // PhysicalDeviceObjectName (R)
    SPDRP_CAPABILITIES = 0x0000000F, // Capabilities (R)
    SPDRP_UI_NUMBER = 0x00000010, // UiNumber (R)
    SPDRP_UPPERFILTERS = 0x00000011, // UpperFilters (R/W)
    SPDRP_LOWERFILTERS = 0x00000012, // LowerFilters (R/W)
    SPDRP_BUSTYPEGUID = 0x00000013, // BusTypeGUID (R)
    SPDRP_LEGACYBUSTYPE = 0x00000014, // LegacyBusType (R)
    SPDRP_BUSNUMBER = 0x00000015, // BusNumber (R)
    SPDRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME = 0x00000016, // Enumerator Name (R)
    SPDRP_SECURITY = 0x00000017, // Security (R/W, binary form)
    SPDRP_SECURITY_SDS = 0x00000018, // Security (W, SDS form)
    SPDRP_DEVTYPE = 0x00000019, // Device Type (R/W)
    SPDRP_EXCLUSIVE = 0x0000001A, // Device is exclusive-access (R/W)
    SPDRP_CHARACTERISTICS = 0x0000001B, // Device Characteristics (R/W)
    SPDRP_ADDRESS = 0x0000001C, // Device Address (R)
    SPDRP_UI_NUMBER_DESC_FORMAT = 0X0000001D, // UiNumberDescFormat (R/W)
    SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA = 0x0000001E, // Device Power Data (R)
    SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY = 0x0000001F, // Removal Policy (R)
    SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_HW_DEFAULT = 0x00000020, // Hardware Removal Policy (R)
    SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_OVERRIDE = 0x00000021, // Removal Policy Override (RW)
    SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE = 0x00000022, // Device Install State (R)
    SPDRP_LOCATION_PATHS = 0x00000023, // Device Location Paths (R)
    SPDRP_BASE_CONTAINERID = 0x00000024  // Base ContainerID (R)
}
```