# Identify port number for device on USB hub

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

I am trying to detect connects and disconnects of USB devices on a given USB hub with information about the port they occurred on.
The hub is a 7-port with known VID and PID that actually consists of two 4-port hubs connected like this (according to [USB Device Tree Viewer](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html)):

> Hub 1
>
> > Hub 2 (Port 1.1) (taken)
> >
> > > Port 2.1 (free)
> > >
> > > Port 2.2 (free)
> > >
> > > Port 2.3 (free)
> > >
> > > Port 2.4 (free)
> >
> > Port 1.2 (free)
> >
> > Port 1.3 (free)
> >
> > Port 1.4 (free)

To detect connection changes I created a `ManagementEventWatcher` using the query `SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'`. Afterwards I would like to use a WMI query to retrieve information about the USB hub, e.g., `SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub WHERE SystemName LIKE '%VID_{vid}&PID_{pid}%'`,

`SELECT * FROM Win32_USBControllerDevice`,

`SELECT * FROM Win32_PnpEntity WHERE DeviceID LIKE 'USB%'`, or similar.

However, neither the EventArgs received by the event watcher, nor any of the results to the queries I came up with seem to contain information about the port on the USB hub itself.

From the USB Device Tree Viewer I also see that a section called "Device Information" contains information I could use to achieve this: `Location IDs`. Connecting to the 4th port on the hub (Port 2.4 above) for example, results in

`[PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0103)#PCI(0000)#USBROOT(0)#USB(21)#USB(1)#USB(4), ...]`

while connecting to the 6th port (Port 1.3 above) results in

`[PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0103)#PCI(0000)#USBROOT(0)#USB(21)#USB(3), ...]`.

Using PowerShell this same exact information can be retrieved using
`Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId "USB\VID_<VID>&PID_<PID>\<ID>"`

What way to retrieve this information in C# am I missing here?

Edit: While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965098/c-sharp-how-do-i-check-usb-ports-with-usb-hub-and-used-controller) asks about a similar topic, the accepted answer does not match the question asked, but rather enumerates different kinds of devices (e.g., mice, graphics cards, disks, ...) without any additional information about the logic location of the device using keys defined in the registry for devices classes that are very limited and do not match generic USB devices.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older thread but I was looking for exactly this and did not find any helpful information anywhere else.
So if anybody else finds themselves in this situation I have found at least a partial solution:

The "Location Information" string (ex. Port_#0003.Hub_#0006) is accessible in the registry at the device root path under the property "LocationInformation".
You can collect the information as seen below. PortInfo is just a small wrapper class i wrote.
The original code was provided by Elmue on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837985/getting-serial-port-information) and I have just modified it a bit.
Disclaimer: This does not provide the full location paths.

```
    public static List<PortInfo> getPortInfos()
    {
        List<PortInfo> ports = new List<PortInfo>();

        using (ManagementClass i_Entity = new ManagementClass("Win32_PnPEntity"))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject i_Inst in i_Entity.GetInstances())
            {
                var o_Guid = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid");
                if (o_Guid == null || o_Guid.ToString().ToUpper() != "{4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}")
                    continue; // Skip all devices except device class "PORTS"

                try
                {
                    string s_Caption = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString();
                    string s_Manufact = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer").ToString();
                    string s_DeviceID = i_Inst.GetPropertyValue("PnpDeviceID").ToString();
                    string s_RegPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\" + s_DeviceID;
                    string s_RegPathDevParams = s_RegPath + "\\Device Parameters";
                    string s_locationInfo = Registry.GetValue(s_RegPath, "LocationInformation", "").ToString();
                    string s_PortName = Registry.GetValue(s_RegPathDevParams, "PortName", "").ToString();

                    int s32_Pos = s_Caption.IndexOf(" (COM");
                    if (s32_Pos > 0) // remove COM port from description
                        s_Caption = s_Caption.Substring(0, s32_Pos);

                    ports.Add(new PortInfo(s_PortName, s_Caption, s_Manufact, s_DeviceID, s_locationInfo));
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException) { }
            }
        }

        return ports;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching a bit more i found this goldmine of a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174169/is-it-possible-to-get-the-pnpdeviceid-of-a-network-adapter-without-using-wmi) by domskey, which finally allowed me to get access to the Location Path attribute. After a few modifications to the code I present you the complete solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Access device information using the setup api
/// Sources:
/// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174169/is-it-possible-to-get-the-pnpdeviceid-of-a-network-adapter-without-using-wmi
/// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw
/// https://www.lifewire.com/device-class-guids-for-most-common-types-of-hardware-2619208
/// https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi/SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.html
/// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837985/getting-serial-port-information
/// </summary>
public class WinPlugAndPlayMediator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches for a device matching the given parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vendorId">The vendor hw id to look for or null if not of interest</param>
    /// <param name="productId">The product hw id to look for or null if not of interest</param>
    /// <param name="onlyComPortDevices">If only com port devices should be considered</param>
    /// <returns>The first device matching all criteria, null if none was found</returns>
    public static DeviceInfo? FindPort(string? vendorId, string? productId)
    {
        return WinPlugAndPlayMediator.GetDeviceInfos()
            .Where(port => vendorId == null || vendorId == port.VendorID)
            .Where(port => productId == null || productId == port.ProductID)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Searches for a device matching the given parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="portName">The COM port name to look for</param>
    /// <returns>The first device matching all criteria, null if none was found</returns>
    public static DeviceInfo? FindPort(string portName)
    {
        return WinPlugAndPlayMediator.GetDeviceInfos()
            .Where(port => portName == null || portName == port.PortName)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches all the connected devices and their information
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeoutMilliseconds"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<DeviceInfo> GetDeviceInfos(int timeoutMilliseconds = 200)
    {
        List<DeviceInfo> devices = new List<DeviceInfo>();

        Guid classGuid = Guid.Empty;
        IntPtr hwndParent = IntPtr.Zero;
        int flags = Win32DeviceMgmt.DIGCF_PRESENT | Win32DeviceMgmt.DIGCF_ALLCLASSES;
        IntPtr pNewDevInfoSet = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            pNewDevInfoSet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, IntPtr.Zero, hwndParent, flags);
            if (pNewDevInfoSet == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get device information list");
                return devices;
            }

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int enumerationIndex = 0;

            while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < timeoutMilliseconds) //Should only take about 100ms for all
            {
                Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = new Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                devInfoData.ClassGuid = Guid.Empty;
                devInfoData.DevInst = 0;
                devInfoData.Reserved = UIntPtr.Zero;
                devInfoData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(devInfoData);

                int result = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(pNewDevInfoSet, enumerationIndex, ref devInfoData);

                if (result == 0)
                {
                    int lastError = Win32DeviceMgmt.GetLastError();

                    if (lastError == Win32DeviceMgmt.ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                    {
                        //Parsed all devices!
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enumerationIndex++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                string instanceId = GetDeviceInstanceId(pNewDevInfoSet, devInfoData);
                string currentLocationPath = GetDevicePropertyString(pNewDevInfoSet, devInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum.SPDRP_LOCATION_PATHS);

                string portClassGuid = "{4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}"; // "Serial and parallel ports"
                string currentClassGuid = GetDevicePropertyString(pNewDevInfoSet, devInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum.SPDRP_CLASSGUID);
                bool serialPortDevice = portClassGuid.ToLower().Equals(currentClassGuid.ToLower());

                devices.Add(new DeviceInfo(instanceId, currentLocationPath, serialPortDevice));

                enumerationIndex++;
            }

            return devices;
        }
        finally
        {
            Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(pNewDevInfoSet);
        }
    }

    public class DeviceInfo
    {
        public string DeviceInstacePath { get; }
        public string LocationPath { get; }

        public string? VendorID { get; }
        public string? ProductID { get; }
        public string? PortName { get; }

        public DeviceInfo(string deviceInstancePath, string locationPath, bool serialPortDevice)
        {
            DeviceInstacePath = deviceInstancePath;
            LocationPath = locationPath;

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"USB\\VID_([0-9a-fA-F]+)&PID_([0-9a-fA-F]+)");
            Match match = regex.Match(deviceInstancePath);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                VendorID = match.Groups[1].Value;
                ProductID = match.Groups[2].Value;
            }

            if (serialPortDevice)
            {
                string registryPath = $"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\{deviceInstancePath}\\Device Parameters";
                PortName = Registry.GetValue(registryPath, "PortName", null)?.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private static String GetDeviceInstanceId(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData)
    {
        StringBuilder strId = new StringBuilder(0);
        Int32 iRequiredSize = 0;
        Int32 iSize = 0;
        Int32 iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData, strId, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);
        strId = new StringBuilder(iRequiredSize);
        iSize = iRequiredSize;
        iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData, strId, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);
        if (iRet == 1)
        {
            return strId.ToString();
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }

    private static String GetDevicePropertyString(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum property)
    {
        byte[] ptrBuf = GetDeviceProperty(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceInfoData, property);
        return ptrBuf.ToStrAuto();
    }

    private static Guid GetDevicePropertyGuid(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum property)
    {
        byte[] ptrBuf = GetDeviceProperty(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceInfoData, property);
        return new Guid(ptrBuf);
    }

    private static byte[] GetDeviceProperty(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum property)
    {
        StringBuilder strId = new StringBuilder(0);
        byte[] ptrBuf = null;
        UInt32 RegType;
        UInt32 iRequiredSize = 0;
        UInt32 iSize = 0;
        bool iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData,
            (uint)property, out RegType, ptrBuf, iSize, out iRequiredSize);
        ptrBuf = new byte[iRequiredSize];
        iSize = iRequiredSize;
        iRet = Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(DeviceInfoSet, ref DeviceInfoData,
            (uint)property, out RegType, ptrBuf, iSize, out iRequiredSize);
        if (iRet)
        {
            return ptrBuf;
        }

        return new byte[0];
    }

}

public static class ByteArrayExtensions
{
    public static string ToStrAuto(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        string ret = "";


        IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, unmanagedPointer, bytes.Length);
            // Call unmanaged code
            ret = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(unmanagedPointer);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

public class Win32DeviceMgmt
{
    internal static Int32 ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES = 259;

    internal static Int32 LINE_LEN = 256;

    internal static Int32 DIGCF_DEFAULT = 0x00000001;  // only valid with DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002;
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x00000004;
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_PROFILE = 0x00000008;
    internal static Int32 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000010;

    internal static Int32 SPINT_ACTIVE = 0x00000001;
    internal static Int32 SPINT_DEFAULT = 0x00000002;
    internal static Int32 SPINT_REMOVED = 0x00000004;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Size of structure in bytes
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 cbSize;
        /// <summary>
        /// GUID of the device interface class
        /// </summary>
        public Guid ClassGuid;
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle to this device instance
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 DevInst;
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved; do not use. 
        /// </summary>
        public UIntPtr Reserved;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Size of the structure, in bytes
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 cbSize;
        /// <summary>
        /// GUID of the device interface class
        /// </summary>
        public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 Flags;
        /// <summary>
        /// Reserved; do not use.
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr Reserved;

    };


    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevsEx(
        ref Guid ClassGuid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String enumerator,
        IntPtr hwndParent, Int32 Flags,
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String MachineName,
        IntPtr Reserved);

    // 1st form using a ClassGUID only, with null Enumerator
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(           
       ref Guid ClassGuid,
       IntPtr Enumerator,
       IntPtr hwndParent,
       int Flags);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        IntPtr DeviceInfoData,
        IntPtr InterfaceClassGuid,
        Int32 MemberIndex,
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        Int32 MemberIndex,
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiClassNameFromGuid(
        ref Guid ClassGuid,
        StringBuilder className,
        Int32 ClassNameSize,
        ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiGetClassDescription(
        ref Guid ClassGuid,
        StringBuilder classDescription,
        Int32 ClassDescriptionSize,
        ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
        StringBuilder DeviceInstanceId,
        Int32 DeviceInstanceIdSize,
        ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    /// <summary>
    /// The SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function retrieves the specified device property.
    /// This handle is typically returned by the SetupDiGetClassDevs or SetupDiGetClassDevsEx function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param Name="DeviceInfoSet">Handle to the device information set that contains the interface and its underlying device.</param>
    /// <param Name="DeviceInfoData">Pointer to an SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure that defines the device instance.</param>
    /// <param Name="Property">Device property to be retrieved. SEE MSDN</param>
    /// <param Name="PropertyRegDataType">Pointer to a variable that receives the registry data Type. This parameter can be NULL.</param>
    /// <param Name="PropertyBuffer">Pointer to a buffer that receives the requested device property.</param>
    /// <param Name="PropertyBufferSize">Size of the buffer, in bytes.</param>
    /// <param Name="RequiredSize">Pointer to a variable that receives the required buffer size, in bytes. This parameter can be NULL.</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.</returns>
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
        IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
        uint Property,
        out UInt32 PropertyRegDataType,
        byte[] PropertyBuffer,
        uint PropertyBufferSize,
        out UInt32 RequiredSize
        );

    // Device Property
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DEVPROPKEY
    {
        public Guid fmtid;
        public UInt32 pid;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern Int32 GetLastError();
}
/// <summary>
/// Flags for SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty().
/// </summary>
enum SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum : uint
{
    SPDRP_DEVICEDESC = 0x00000000, // DeviceDesc (R/W)
    SPDRP_HARDWAREID = 0x00000001, // HardwareID (R/W)
    SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS = 0x00000002, // CompatibleIDs (R/W)
    SPDRP_UNUSED0 = 0x00000003, // unused
    SPDRP_SERVICE = 0x00000004, // Service (R/W)
    SPDRP_UNUSED1 = 0x00000005, // unused
    SPDRP_UNUSED2 = 0x00000006, // unused
    SPDRP_CLASS = 0x00000007, // Class (R--tied to ClassGUID)
    SPDRP_CLASSGUID = 0x00000008, // ClassGUID (R/W)
    SPDRP_DRIVER = 0x00000009, // Driver (R/W)
    SPDRP_CONFIGFLAGS = 0x0000000A, // ConfigFlags (R/W)
    SPDRP_MFG = 0x0000000B, // Mfg (R/W)
    SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME = 0x0000000C, // FriendlyName (R/W)
    SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION = 0x0000000D, // LocationInformation (R/W)
    SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME = 0x0000000E, // PhysicalDeviceObjectName (R)
    SPDRP_CAPABILITIES = 0x0000000F, // Capabilities (R)
    SPDRP_UI_NUMBER = 0x00000010, // UiNumber (R)
    SPDRP_UPPERFILTERS = 0x00000011, // UpperFilters (R/W)
    SPDRP_LOWERFILTERS = 0x00000012, // LowerFilters (R/W)
    SPDRP_BUSTYPEGUID = 0x00000013, // BusTypeGUID (R)
    SPDRP_LEGACYBUSTYPE = 0x00000014, // LegacyBusType (R)
    SPDRP_BUSNUMBER = 0x00000015, // BusNumber (R)
    SPDRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME = 0x00000016, // Enumerator Name (R)
    SPDRP_SECURITY = 0x00000017, // Security (R/W, binary form)
    SPDRP_SECURITY_SDS = 0x00000018, // Security (W, SDS form)
    SPDRP_DEVTYPE = 0x00000019, // Device Type (R/W)
    SPDRP_EXCLUSIVE = 0x0000001A, // Device is exclusive-access (R/W)
    SPDRP_CHARACTERISTICS = 0x0000001B, // Device Characteristics (R/W)
    SPDRP_ADDRESS = 0x0000001C, // Device Address (R)
    SPDRP_UI_NUMBER_DESC_FORMAT = 0X0000001D, // UiNumberDescFormat (R/W)
    SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA = 0x0000001E, // Device Power Data (R)
    SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY = 0x0000001F, // Removal Policy (R)
    SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_HW_DEFAULT = 0x00000020, // Hardware Removal Policy (R)
    SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_OVERRIDE = 0x00000021, // Removal Policy Override (RW)
    SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE = 0x00000022, // Device Install State (R)
    SPDRP_LOCATION_PATHS = 0x00000023, // Device Location Paths (R)
    SPDRP_BASE_CONTAINERID = 0x00000024  // Base ContainerID (R)
}
```

A few tips:

- If you don't need the information of all devices and execution time is critical to your application I would suggest you check inside the while loop for the device you are interested in and abort the search after that.
  It takes up to 100ms to execute the whole loop on my system.
- Take a look at SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyEnum for additional information you might be interested in.
- If you only want devices of a specific type (eg. only interested in serial port devices) you can remove the Win32DeviceMgmt.DIGCF_ALLCLASSES flag and instead define a non empty [classGuid](https://www.lifewire.com/device-class-guids-for-most-common-types-of-hardware-2619208). The devices returned will then all be only of that type.
- I think you can also specifically search for one device using the classGuid and removing the flag mentioned above. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw) writes about that, but I was unable to figure out how to do it exactly and couldn't be bothered to spend any longer on this class.
- For completeness I left in every part of the code that might be useful, however not everything is used. I would suggest you remove the parts you don't need.